# Screen freezes, mouse moves

Tags: 18.04, mouse, screen, radeon, freeze

I have seen different questions with screen freezes and I finally thought it was Chrome, so I disabled hardware acceleration etc., only to find out it was not the same issue.

The problem seems to occur when I move a (Chrome?) window fast from one desktop to another. Then the screen freezes with only the mouse moving. I can control the machine with ssh, but it is very annoying to have to reboot over and over again.

I guess it would be a hard issue to debug. Ah, using a Radeon video card. Tried different drivers, etc. as far as I remember and keep my system updated.

Hope someone can find this, as it is very annoying and kind of makes my system unusable.

Comment: I notice it seems to happen when I move a window from one desktop to another. Mostly with a Chrome window, but now I saw it with a VLC video that was playing.

Comment: And I noticed it seems to have to do with part of a window off the screen, as I moved a VLC window showing a movie partly off screen and then the system got stuck again. The mouse seems always in 'busy' mode when it happens and it only seems to happen with (fast) window movement.